# How to remove line from file in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm currently trying to remove lines from a file using LISP.

```lisp
(defun remove_line_from_file (file line_number)
    
)

(defun remove_lines_from_file (file lines)
    (if (not (null lines))
        (progn
            (remove_line_from_file (file (car (sort lines #'>))))
            (remove_lines_from_file (file (cdr (sort lines #'>))))
        )
    )
)
```

I have no idea how I can do that. What I did was the recursion.

An example of call:

```lisp
(remove_lines_from_file "file_name" (2 3 5 6))
```

How can I delete a specified line from a file?

```lisp
(remove_line_from_file "file_name" 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes:

1. `snake_case` is not Lispy, use `lisp-case` (a.k.a. kebab case)
2. `sort` mutates its argument, so in your case it has side-effects on the input list; you would need to do `(sort (copy-list list) ...)` instead.
3. you seem to be trying to recurse on `lines`, which looks like it would be inefficient; you probably want to iterate over the file once

You need to open the file for reading, iterate over all lines while incrementing a line counter, and copy each line (e.g. write to standard output) except when the line number is one of the lines to remove:

```
(defun remove-lines (file lines-to-remove)
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (loop
      for line-number from 1
      for line = (read-line in nil nil)
      while line
      unless (member line-number lines-to-remove)
        do (write-line line))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices. It's working now, but how can I write them back into the file?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You can't open simultaneously for reading and write, so either you redirect the standard output to a different file, or you store all the lines in memory, close the input stream, open the file for writing and write all the lines back. In the example you would write `collect line` instead of `do (write-sttring line)` and the function would return a list of lines. Writing all the lines in a list into a file would be something like `(with-open-file (out file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede) (dolist (line list) (write-string line out) (terpri out)))`

Comment: Thanks, I stored them with ```(setq lines (loop for line-number ...``` and then wrote them in the file with your solution.